# Imaging plotly figure as image in jupyterq using embedpy

Tags: jupyter, kdb, embedpy

When I try t display a plotly graph from pyhton as image that works fine

```
import plotly.express as px
from IPython.display import Image

fig = px.scatter(x=range(10), y=range(10))
Image(fig.to_image(format="png"))
```

However, when I try the same via embedpy from jupyterq, the graph wont display

```
px:.p.import[`plotly.express]
ipd:.p.import[`IPython.display]

fig:px[`:scatter][`x pykw til 10; `y pykw til 10]
img:fig[`:to_image][`format pykw `png]
ipd[`:Image][img]
```

The graph wont display. I also tried actively displaying it

```
ipd[`:display][ipd[`:Image][img]]
```

But this just shows tiny generic image thumbnail

The regular plotly graph displays fine

```
fig[`:show][]
```

Also, trying to execute the python code via .p.e does not show the image, but just the thumbnail

```
.p.e["import plotly.express as px"]
.p.e["from IPython.display import Image, display"]
.p.e["fig=px.scatter(x=range(10), y=range(10))"]
.p.e["Image(fig.to_image(format='png'))"]
.p.e["display(Image(fig.to_image(format='png')))"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be in .qpk.mc function. Two ways to fix this, provided by a co-worker:

Either overriding the offending function

```
.qpk.mc:{y}
```

Inject into an html that can handle the encoded string

```
ipd[`:display]ipd[`:HTML]["<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,",.b64.enc[img`],"\">"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for highlighting the issue, at the moment we do not currently have a fix for this, but an issue has been raised on GitHub https://github.com/KxSystems/jupyterq/issues/55 and it is being looked into.

Comment: Thanks for picking this up. I added some workarounds as a solution below